# Wordpress plugins - how to change page title?

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone know of a way to change the page title in a Wordpress plugin? I've looked for hooks and functions to do it but have turned up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this page

http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

the title is one of the arguments to the add_menu_page

```
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
```